# What is the XPath equivalent of the Coalesce operator?

Tags: xpath

I have the following paths:

- /my:company/ns1:Audit/ns1:Visit/ns1:customField10
- /my:company/ns1:Audit/ns1:Visit/ns1:accountNumber

I want to select ns1:customField10 if it is not empty, otherwise I want to return ns1:accountNumber.

I tried the following:

```
xml.SelectSingleNode(
    "(/my:cobius/ns1:Audit/ns1:Visit/ns1:customField10 | 
    /my:cobius/ns1:Audit/ns1:Visit/ns1:accountNumber)", ns)
```

But it is always returning accountNumber. I tried flipping the order of customField10 and accountNumber, but no joy. It still returns accountNumber.

How can I do the equivalent of the coalesce operator in XPath?

Update:

Here's the final code:

```
xml.SelectSingleNode(
    "(/my:company/ns1:Audit/ns1:Visit/ns1:customField10[normalize-space()] | 
    /my:company/ns1:Audit/ns1:Visit/ns1:accountNumber[not(normalize-space(../ns1:customField10))])", ns)
```

Comment: Why not do `xml.SelectSingleNode()` for both nodes and a normal `if ...` after that?

Comment: It might be easier to answer your question if you told us what the coalesce operator is, or at any rate, which technology you are thinking of that has such an operator.

Comment: @Tomalak For the same reason I'd use a coalesce operator in SQL or C#. Why not do it inline rather than assign two variables and do a check?

Comment: @Michael Kay - I explain what I want to do in the question, but for examples of coalesce see: [C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx), [MSSQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx), [Oracle](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/coalesce.php)

Comment: @Rich "Doing things in one line" is not "inlining". In any case, extracting two distinct nodes from a document and comparing their contents in C# is likely more efficient than building a complex XPath expression that *seemingly* (!) does it in one step. Besides, there is no "coalesce" operation in XPath.

Comment: @Tomalak - perhaps you should add an "even though you can do this, you shouldn't" answer rather than making that case in comments. I'm willing to change my code if the true answer to "What is the XPath equivalent of the Coalesce operator?" is "There isn't".

Comment: Well, yeah. There really isn't. You could use `(node1, node2)[1]` in XPath 2.0, but only because XPath 2.0 is sequence-order-oriented. In contrast, XPath 1.0 is document-order-oriented (*and* it does not have a comma operator) so this will not work there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code would work if the node was missing (kind of equivalent to a NULL in SQL). But empty is not missing (like an empty string in SQL).

You can of course add a predicate:

```
/my:cobius/ns1:Audit/ns1:Visit/ns1:customField10[string-length(.)] | /my:cobius/ns1:Audit/ns1:Visit/ns1:accountNumber
```

Comment: Actually, more like `/foo[string-length()] | /bar[not(/foo[string-length()])]`

Comment: `|` is not some sort of short-circuiting logical-or. It's a union operator. In other words, if both exist, you'll get both, which is not what the OP wants.

Comment: @lwburk: Not necessarily, see above comment. ;)

Comment: @Tomalak - Didn't see your comment until after I hit submit. That's more like it.

Comment: @Tomalak - Although I'd probably prefer `[normalize-space()]` to `[string-length()]`

Comment: The OP is doing a `SelectSingleNode`, which returns the first node of the set. Therefore it isn't a problem is the set contains both nodes. There is, however, a caveat which I should have mentionned: the code expects the `customField10` to be before `accountNumber` in the document, since the union operator returns the node in document order.

Comment: @Lucero Right, that's why I made the mutually exclusive predicates. However, I'd say that this is not an operation you would want to force on XPath 1.0. It's much easier to do that in the host language.

Comment: I had trouble making this example work, but it inspired a different solution: (/foo/text() | /bar/text())[last()]  - Yes, it assumes the 'optional' one is last in the document, but if that is not the case, I'm guessing [first()] would work.

Comment: That would be `[1]` rather than `[first()]`